# Dynamic column based on class names in LESS

Tags: less

I'm trying to do something like this

```
            .col-@{index} {
                width: @col-n-width;
                left: {index - 1 } * @col-n-width;
            }
```

But not sure how to access the {index} variable inside.  Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@{}` syntax is used only when you need to interpolate variables in property names or selectors or URLs etc. It is not required when all you need to do is plain math operations. Just reference it as `@index` like in the below sample.

```css
.col-@{index} {
  width: @col-n-width;
  left: (@index - 1) * @col-n-width;
}
```

For example if you are trying to write a loop/mixin, the code would be something like the below:

```
@col-n-width: 200px;

.create-cols(@index) when (@index > 0) {
  .col-@{index} {
    width: @col-n-width;
    left: (@index - 1) * @col-n-width;
  }
  .create-cols(@index - 1);
}
.create-cols(5);
```

**Note:** The `@index` must be a variable defined in your Less file. Less compiler cannot read the HTML and dynamically create classes based on it. In the worst case, you'd at least have to use client-side compilation through JS using [`less.modifyVars()`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-modify-variables) but [client-side compilation of code is generally not recommended](http://lesscss.org/usage/#browser-support).